# Assigning a text value to a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, forms

`<input type="radio" name="package" value="SOME_VALUE_HERE">`

I am using Joomla but i think its something related to PHP. I have a form on my website, and it has **RADIO button** , what i want is when the user submits the form with that **RADIO BUTTON** selected, in place of the value (**SOME_VALUE_HERE**) , i want something else to get stored in the database. That something should a 10-15 liner text. Can i make a **$PHP variable** and assign that 10-15 liner text to that variable and use it in place of the value=(**SOME_VALUE_HERE**).

Example :

`<input type="radio" value="$phpvariable">`

Where **$phpvariable** is a 10-15 liner text!

Hope you got my point!

Comment: `$phpvariable = 'long ass test string here';`

Comment: If that long text is not shown to end-user, you don't have to put it in an HTML page and get it back. Keep it in server-side instead (in a variable in `$_SESSION`) and retrieve it from there based on end-user's selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use php-tags and echo the php variable in the value of the input:

Assign value to php variable:

```
<?php $phpvariable = 'SOME LONG TEXT HERE'; ?>
```

The input:

```
<input type="radio" name="package" value="<?php echo $phpvariable; ?>">
```

You will also need a name for your input so that you can get the value

Comment: how will assign the value to $phpvariable ?

Comment: <?php $phpvariable = 'SOME LONG TEXT HERE'; ?>

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. It's helpful for others with similar problems :)

Comment: it all worked fine..but i am having a prob. with this.. the value which gets stored in the database is "spaceless". I mean the sentence "this is a book" is stored as "thisisabook" ...!?

Comment: Think I need some more code and info about the database to be able to help you further.

Comment: Like how you handle the variable after submit and how you insert it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try:

```
<input type="radio" name="package" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">
```

If that does not work, just create a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="packageHidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">
```

function htmlspecialchars prevents XSS attacks as well.

Comment: dude! how to assign the value to $name? that's my question!

Comment: <?php $name = "your needed value"; ?> :)